# Is the tense shifting in the first paragraph acceptable?

Tags: tense, future-tense, present-simple

1. The Qinghai Tibet Railway, the highest in the world, **begins**
   operation on Saturday. 【The first train **will leave** Golmud, the second
   largest city of Qinghai Province in Northwest China, for Lhasa, in
   the Tibet Autonomous Region, in the morning.】
2. The train **leaves** Golmud at about 2,800 meters above sea level, **winds** through the towering  Tanggula Mountain Pass at 5, 072 metres, and finally **arrives** in Lhasa at 3, 650 metres .
3. A ceremony **will be held** at the Golmud Railway Station at about 9: 30 am to see off the train, according to sources with the Ministry of Railways. At least 1,000 journalists from home and abroad have come to Qinghai and Tibet to cover the  event along the rail line. People can witness the ceremony and the whole day's trip live on television, radio and...

The paragraphs are excerpted from a English translation of a Chinese news report. I understand that the translator uses mostly **simple present tense** to indicate the railway's opening and the train's timetable was planned and somewhat unlikely to change. What confuses me is the square bracketed sentence in the 1st paragraph shifts to **"future tense"(will leave)**. I think using "will" loses the certainty and the inconsistency in tenses makes readers think that as opposed to the railway's fixed schedule, "the train might not leave Golmud in the morning".  Am I right or am I just being picky...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concern is over switching between *will* and *present simple* because as you state:

*"I think using "will" loses the certainty."*

The *Present Simple* is used as you correctly state for a fixed plan.

*Will* is no weaker in this usage. In fact in some regards it is more certain because it is 'untouchable'.

What do I mean by that?

Well *will* is used for predictions based on fact

> The ice will melt very soon here.

and *will* is used for future facts

> I will be 42 on my next birthday.

These events cannot be stopped without a complete change of circumstance. So *will* can convey more certainty than the *present simple*.

In fact one use of *will* is as the modal of certainty/determination.

> I don't care what you say, I will do it.

The *present simple* however does not communicate such inevitability of the future, just the rigidness of the present.

Compare the present focus of

> The exam is on Friday, I better study today.

and the future inevitability of

> The exam will be on Friday whatever the weather.

For more information on the use of will see my blog post
https://www.englishadam.com/learn.php?content=63&src=1

That being said there is little perceived difference and the issue about switching tenses can be a matter of preference, we certainly switch tenses mid-paragraph!

Comment: I agree with your analysis, but what stuck out like a sore thumb was "The exam is Friday, I better study today". "Had better" is a modal for recommendation, the "had" is part of the phrase, you can't leave it out. The example should be "The exam is Friday, I'd better study today."

Comment: @Karen927 "I better" is perfectly acceptable informal English, please see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/236948/id-better-vs-i-better

Comment: no. I don't care what rules people are trying to make up as they go along. "Had better" is a modal, not "better". Would you advocate for people dropping the "have" helper for present perfect as well?

Comment: @Karen927, well you are quite prescriptive about English usage then, which is ironic here because "had better" itself reflects a deviation from a previous standard of English. Please see https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/origin-of-had-better.2642605/ . Interesting stuff, note how "better do" is again cited as 'casual' in usage.

Comment: What is "casual" usage? Is that a euphemism for anything goes? If so, would that make "would of" an acceptable form of "would have"?

Answer (score 1):

They're fine. The modal expression *will go* and the so-called present *goes* are usually freely interchangeable for future events, as long as futurity is established in some way.

I can't find any difference in meaning between *It leaves in the morning* and *It will leave in the morning*.